# ng-model not seeming to bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass values of `input`'s back to the controller using `ng-model`.

I have tried setting the `ng-model` to `email`, but, when logged to the console, returned `undefined`.
I've has a look at these 2 sources:

- [Why is my ng-model variable undefined in controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455718/why-is-my-ng-model-variable-undefined-in-controller#23456183)
- http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

But, when I have used the dot notation, nothing is logged to the console at all. *(not even `'Email: '`)*

I only get the error of:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

**HTML:**

```
<ion-view title="Register" hide-nav-bar="true" nav-transition="none" id="page9">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="manual-ios-statusbar-padding" scroll="false">
        <form id="register-form4" class="list">
            <ion-list id="register-list4">
                <label class="item item-input" id="register-input7">
                    <input type="email" ng-model="reg.email" placeholder="Email">
                </label>
               <label class="item item-input" id="register-input9">
                   <input type="password" ng-model="reg.password" placeholder="Password">
               </label>
           </ion-list>
           <a ui-sref="tabsController.myTrips" id="register-button7" ng-click="register()" class="button button-positive  button-block">Create Account</a>
           <a ui-sref="login" id="register-button8" class="button button-positive  button-block button-clear">Back</a>
           <div ng-show="isError">{{ loginError }}</div>
       </form>
   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('registerCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', "$firebaseAuth",
function ($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseAuth) {
    $scope.register = function() {
        var email = $scope.reg.email,
            password = $scope.reg.password;

        console.log("Email: " + email);
        console.log("Password: " + password);

        // ...
    }
}])
```

Also, I have played around with the HTML type (changed it to `text`) but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is this:

You are using `$scope.reg.email`, but you have not initialized `$scope.reg`. In your controller constructor, you need a line like this:

```
$scope.reg = {};
```

Without that, `$scope.reg` is undefined and you get the "Cannot read property 'email' of undefined" error.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept the answer when I can