# $scope returns undefined in ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am wondering at the dual behaviour of $scope. In the below script I am getting value of `name` as alert. But in my ionic app the same code alerts `undefined`.

I googled the problem and found [this link](http://www.yourtechchick.com/angularjs/ng-model-undefined-on-scope/) as a solution where it states that we need to use dot(.) in order to get the value in `ng-model`. What is the difference between two.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.a =function a(){alert($scope.name);}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Name: <input ng-model="name" ng-blur="a()">
</div>
```

Comment: try using $scope.a =  function(val){alert(val);} and <input ng-model="name" ng-blur="a(name)">

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your controller function as below:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.a =function(){
        alert($scope.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: No, now it is $scope.a =function a(){alert($scope.name);}   ('function a')

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does work with Ionic,

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.a = function a() {
    alert($scope.name);
  }

})
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/4OFDOQ8frnKczNKAHsZZ?p=info)**

Comment: I am using `starter.controllers` in my module

Comment: i dont get  what you are saying

Comment: In your answer you asked me to use 'starter.controllers'  instead of 'myApp' that is exactly what i am doing

Comment: @sam that does not matter actually,  i have changed and still it works https://plnkr.co/edit/4OFDOQ8frnKczNKAHsZZ?p=preview

Comment: hi @Sajeetharan . Your demo works good. but kindly explain what is the problem from OP code?.

Comment: @RameshRajendran There should not be any errror unless the controller gets re instantiated

Comment: I thought this same. I think OP missed something like that.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution :

*"If you use ng-model, you have to have a dot in there."*

Make your model point to an object.property and you'll be good to go.

**Controller**

```
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.check = function () {
  console.log($scope.formData.searchText.$modelValue); //works
}
```

**Template**

```
<input ng-model="formData.searchText"/>
<button ng-click="check()">Check!</button>
```

This happens when child scopes are in play - like child routes or ng-repeats.
The child-scope creates it's own value and a name conflict is born [as illustrated here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBwoFkRjZvE&t=3m15s):

See this video clip for more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBwoFkRjZvE&t=3m15s
.

And that is referred from below links :

### Other Solutions

> Use `this` keyword instead of `$scope`, [More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25958746/2218635)

---

---

***And also you can get more details from this below two discussions***

[Ng-model does not update controller value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618342/ng-model-does-not-update-controller-value/22768720#22768720)

[Why is my ng-model variable undefined in controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455718/why-is-my-ng-model-variable-undefined-in-controller)

---

### Update Solution 1 :

Please declaring the blank object first at the top of your controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.a = function(){alert($scope.name);}
});
```

I hope these will be helps to you.

Comment: But in the above snippet you can see that I am not using 'dot' with ng-model but it still gives the correct output

Comment: I think it may be threw the problem for `$parent` and `$child`manipulation.  let me know if my all solution is not works to you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use json object.

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.user = {'name':''};
        $scope.a =function a(){alert($scope.user.name);}
    });

 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Name: <input ng-model="user.name" ng-blur="a()">
</div>
```